# How to convert JS MediaStream to numpy array

Tags: machine-learning, next.js, socket.io, opencv, mediastream, python

I wanted to integrate a ML project with Nextjs for realtime interaction.

I am using Mediapipe model for real time face detection. One of the crucial step involved in there is

```
results = model.process(image)
```

where `image` is an array of pixel colors of a single frame captured with `cv2` 
and `model` is a pre-trained MediaPipe Holistic model.

Now on the frontend side of it I can access user's webcam with `navigator.mediaDevices` and obtain a `MediaStream` for user's video. I am aware of socketio and webRTC for real time communication but I can't seem to figure out how will I convert my MediaStream to python array.

Also will this be really feasible in real time? I will have to send user stream to backend, let the model calculate result and send the result back to frontend to display.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure about converting to numpy directly, but we can convert it to tensor by using `tf.browser.fromPixels()`.

1. first draw the video content onto the canvas
2. from canvas `tf.browser.fromPixels(canvas)`

```js
// Querying and creating context

const canvas = document.querySelector('.class')

let ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    
// draw the video onto the canvas

ctx.drawImage(video,0,0,width,height);
    
// Now the video content is drawn into canvas we can access through canvas

tensor = tf.browser.fromPixels(canvas)
```

You can easily play around with this tensor using tensorflowjs library.